# Move Magento to WAMP

Tags: magento, wamp, local

I am trying to clone a Magento site to wamp and after accessing the local site from Wamp server (localhost) it redirects me to the online version of the site.

I modified `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` from `core_config_data` table to "localhost/my_local_site", where the local version of the site is saved.

After I add `127.0.0.1       www.my_site.com` to hosts file and turn offline, the local site is loading the first page (index) but the other pages are not loading.

Do you have any ideas what I should do to make the local version of the site work?

Comment: Try replacing all the entries in the database containing www.yoursite.com to 127.0.0.1. But make sure you have some backup before making changes

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the database name and user in etc/local.xml
2. Change the links in your db at core_config_data to localhost or
   whatever name your localhost has.
3. Delete cache and sessions from the localhost folders.

Hopes it helps